# React on click call API and create csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, csv, react-router

I'm working on a React app served by a RoR backend. I want to have a button that, when clicked, will query the server for the required data and create the CSV for download in the users browser.

I'm pretty versed in the Rails side of things but I'm not at all sure how to go about doing this on the React side (or even if that's the best order to do it in as I've seen some answers saying it might be better to do the API call when the component initially mounts).

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Could you clarify where you want to create the CSV? Do you mean you want to generate the CSV in the browser (as opposed to making an API call and having the server return the CSV file)?

Comment: I'd like for the CSV to be created for the user to download in their browser but hopefully not store it in our application, since that could end up with a lot of bulk if a lot of people download it. I assumed that had to happen on the React side since the Rails side doesn't have views, just serves the React side with data, but I don't really care which as long as I get the desired functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem here is that you can't download a file via AJAX -- browsers don't allow it. The only solution is to render a static form in your react component, save a reference to it, and manually submit it when you click your button. Here's an example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.onClickDownload = this.onClickDownload.bind(this)
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <form style={{display: 'none'}} method="POST" action="/api/reports/export"
            ref={(el) => {this.exportForm = el}}>
          </form>

          <button onClick={this.onClickDownload}>Download CSV</button>
        </div>
      )
    }

    onClickDownload() {
      this.exportForm.submit()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but not working. This line seems not right `<button onClick={onClick={}>Download CSV</button>`

Comment: @SomeSchmo my bad, there was a typo in my code. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I would propose you have an endpoint in your Rails app that accepts parameters for the CSV report. This endpoint gets hit when the user presses the button.

The Rails app would create the CSV, put it somewhere (maybe S3 using https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), and return an S3 URL to the React app. The user could then go to that URL and download the file.

It's probably best to generate the CSV asynchronously to not tie up resources. In that case, the frontend could poll (or use a websocket) and wait until the report is ready. When it's ready, the API would return the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution with form with form will, but why not just use a link and style it like a button. This way you can even have a GET request

```
render() {
  return ()
   <a href='api/reports/export'>Download CSV</a>
 }
```